# Red Hat Enterprise Linux desktop: constant crashing, unusable, what to do

Tags: rhel

I'm having constant problems with RHEL recently. My desktop crashes during the day occasionally (once a day roughly) and is hung (black screen) every morning requiring a button-hitting restart.

Clicking the "kernel crash dumps" menu item does nothing. I'm wondering if it's to do with the latest round of redhat updates but I don't want to just unwind updates on mere suspicion.

Anybody else hating Red Hat this week? How can I view the crash dumps?

2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 20 12:17:37 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.4 (Santiago)

Already have this installed too:

```
yum install kexec-tools crash kernel-debuginfo kernel-debuginfo-common system-config-kdump
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
rhel-x86_64-workstation-6                                                                                                                                                                                              | 1.8 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Package kexec-tools-2.0.0-258.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package crash-6.1.0-1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package kernel-debuginfo available.
No package kernel-debuginfo-common available.
Package system-config-kdump-2.0.5-15.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

And:

```
grep -v "#" /etc/kdump.conf 

path /var/crash
core_collector makedumpfile -c --message-level 1 -d 31
```

Comment: Basically I've had a look at this: /crashkrushersdomain.blogspot.ca/2012/03/how-to-generate-crash-dump-on-redhat.html but haven't actually tried to cause a crash ...

Comment: This sounds like it might be best taken to the folks at Red Hat support.

Comment: In any case, what's your graphics card? Do you use a screensaver program overnight, or just the blank screen? Are you doing anything in particular when it crashes while in use?

Comment: Can you switch to a VT when you get the black screen?

Comment: I don't think I can switch to VT ... I'll try again next time it hangs with a black screen.

Comment: If you find you can switch to a VT, then the problem is with X. This might mean a hung GPU and would point to @mattdm's hunch about the Graphics driver being true. If that's the case, look under your home directory for the file `.xsession-errors` and look for any weird error messages there.

Comment: I can't switch to VT ... the monitor lights go yellow like there is no signal. I think this means the problem is deeper than X, but I'm really just guessing at this point.

Comment: Hahaha ... AND I can't seem to submit a support case. The page https://access.redhat.com/support/cases/new/ gives: Exception event id: 175574d721304e9db804199c0cc699c75975c17fcad399529902a5c2815f5c29

Comment: Check if the keyboard LEDs react, if they do the machine isn't truly hung. Also try to connect over the network, that might let you check for any wedged processes and in general "see" the problem in action.

Comment: The keyboard LEDS do *not* react. I think that means it has really crashed.

Comment: Downgraded a kernel version to the previous 358 and still have the overnight crashes. Now trying 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64.

Comment: If the system is creating a lot of "random" irregularities, check the memory with a good memory tester.  One thing to check is whether you can ping or ssh into the box from another one on the network, if it's networked.  That will give another indication of whether it's entirely hung or more likely a display-related issue.